# Test Automation: Automate outgoing calls from fixed phones registered with a Skype for Business IP-PBX

Tags: skype-for-business, ucma

For test automation purposes, we're currently investigating upon how we can have a fixed phone registered with a Skype for Business IP-PBX (e.g. an AudioCodes phone or a Yealink phone or...), make an outgoing call upon request.

E.g. Our test automation platform would send a request to the Skype for Business Server to tell this server to initiate an outgoing call from phone A registered with that Skype for Business Server to an external phone B. So a little bit similar as JTAPI functionality...

I.e. Would this be feasible by using UCMA 5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to SIP to make a physical phone make a call.

With UCMA you are effectively a softphone, so with UCMA you can make your "softphone" make a call.

With the Lync Client API you are remote controlling the Lync Client (Skype for Business client), so with the Lync Client API you can remote control the Lync Client to make a call.

The only way I can think of to make a physical phone dial would be to use a Polycom VVX phone linked to a instance of a Lync Client using there "Better Together" application.  Then you can use the Lync Client API to remote control the Lync Client which would in turn remote control the Polycom VVX phone.

Comment: With the Lync client API, do you mean then the Skype Desktop API? Isn't this API getting deprecated for use with Skype For Business 2015 Server? The pairing of a Polycom phone with a softclient by means of BToE is indeed something which can be used here... If this Lync Client API can be used with the new Skype For Business Server SW of course...

Comment: I don't know "Skype Desktop API", is that for consumer Skype?  Lync Client SDK works with SfB client but is slowly breaking due to not being updated in a long time, but it mainly still works.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=36824

Comment: The Skype Desktop API enables third party applications to communicate with Skype. Anyway, I'll try to figure out how I can control the Skype Soft Clients by means of the Lync Client SDK. And then afterwards I'll pair those up with IP phones through BToE... Thanks for the information!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in a Skype/Lync environment but I've done something similar in Asterisk a long time ago. I don't remember all the details of the test any more.

One key to get hardware involved, if you don't use a BToE connection, is to leverage the "Auto Answer" answer feature on most handsets.

I have seen some phones also allow for some push/curl commands to be sent to the device. An example of this with a polycom is [here](https://community.polycom.com/t5/VoIP-SIP-Phones/XML-push-action/m-p/30882/highlight/true#M4425). The post is old and it's been years since I messed with that, but I assume some of that function may still be in some devices/firmware. I haven't seen anything similar with AudioCodes or Yealink, but they maybe there as well.